# PI3 Ubuntu Server 16.04.03 - UART issue

Tags: pi-3, boot, ubuntu, uart

I'm trying to setup UART, for a final year project at university, on the PI3, I need to switch ttyAMA0 to the GPIO pins in place of ttyS0.
I have tried adding the device tree overlays 'pi3-disable-bt' and 'pi3-miniuart-bt' to the config.txt found in /boot, however it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

I have noticed that /boot/overlays does not exist on this version, so I attempted to paste the .dtbo's (aquired from raspberrypi@github) into the /boot folder but this did nothing.

Any advice good sir's?
Thanks!